# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "1234567891011"

Tags: java

```
input:- 1 3 4 7 9 6 -1
output:- 4 6
```

What I am doing is print the even numbers from the list, one per line. The list ends when -1 is encountered. Below is the my code:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i <100000000; i++) {
int z=sc.nextInt();
    if(z != -1)
    {
        if(z%2==0)
        {
            System.out.println(z);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This code is working for maximum of input but giving error when I will give below number as a input . How to remove is this:

```
1234567891011
1234575135480
4357941369468
3246896421457
4356899643456
9753567886447
7545786575675
4675676788975
4523533536642
2412345546756
8678789685674
5632523414215
5435656765786
4676789879674
3562345245356
4675877956734
5452421425445
6758795674562
3421767655359
2124535456560
-1
```

Comment: 2^31-1 is the Max value you values are too high

Comment: Try using `long long int` for these values

Comment: @coderzz027 you mean just ``long``? There is no such thing as ``long long int``.

Comment: yes, it is working with long...@thanks All

Comment: @f1sh I have been using `long long` in c++, so I thought there's probably a `long long` in Java as well.. Probably there isn't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range.

Integer.MIN_VALUE: -2147483648

Integer.MAX_VALUE: 2147483647

Instead of int use long

```
long z = sc.nextLong();
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the exeception from the `Scanner.nextInt();` call.

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

The [exeception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) is thrown because the values are to high.
Integer [MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) is 2^31-1, all of your values are too high.

You should use long which has a [MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) of 2^63-1.

Answer (score 0):

Max value an int can hold is 2147483647.

Use double.